# (Java Swing) JTextField updates "too late"

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, keylistener

This is a code sample from a feet<->meters converter. My problem: It doesn't update the current input, for example: If the text in the JTextField is "50", the `textField.getText()`only gives the String "5", so the `double result` would be 5.0. As a consequence, a "5" in the JTextField gives an error in `double result = Double.parseDouble(textField.getText());` "Empty String". Thanks in advance for your answers!

```
public static void addKL(JTextField textField, JTextField textField2, String name) {

    textField.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent evt) {
            if(evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_1||evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_2||evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_3||evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_4||evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_5||evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_6||evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_7||evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_9||evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_COLON||evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE                           ) {
                double result = Double.parseDouble(textField.getText());
                if(name=="ftFIELD") {
                    textField2.setText("" + result/3.2808);
                }
                else if(name=="mFIELD") {
                    textField2.setText("" + result*3.2808);
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Note: Ofcourse an else is missing if the KeyEvent isnt valid, but I didn't want to continue coding before this error isn't fixed.

Comment: `name=="ftFIELD"` Use the `equals` method when comparing String objects.

Comment: the method never enter into  [if-else statements](too check this try a System.out.println("I entered here")) If it doesn't enter (i am soore it will not) you have to use  name.equals("ftFIELD") in java the == isn't like int [[C]]

Comment: The keylistener will be invoked each time a number is entered. So you need to keep reading the field, updating the other field each time a key is pressed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the wrong event, try `keyReleased` instead. Also fixed the string comparison

```
    text.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent evt) {
            if(evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_1||evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_2||evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_3||evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_4||evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_5||evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_6||evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_7||evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_9||evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_COLON||evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE                           ) {
                double result = Double.parseDouble(text.getText());

                if("ftFIELD".equals(name)) {
                    textField2.setText("" + result/3.2808);
                }
                else if("mFIELD".equals(name)) {
                    textField2.setText("" + result*3.2808);
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: `KeyListener` is a poor choice for monitoring changes to any text field, the order which they notify listeners is undefined (so they key event could be consumed before your listener), doesn't take into account what happens when text is pasted into the field and could cause a mutation exception

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `KeyListener` with text components, a user may paste text into the field which won't be picked up by your listener.

Instead, if you want to know when the field is modified, you should use a `DocumentListener`. See [Listening for Changes on a Document](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#doclisteners) for more details